# Using bitbucket for VCS in Android Studio

Tags: git, version-control, terminal, bitbucket

I have using bitbucket as VCS for last few months.
Today I was poking some code on Terminal and some how created multiple copies of same file. Then doing google I see a code like : `git rm -r .`
Thought this would remove my data and then I would download them from repo.
The after few minutes I dont knw why but I commit the change to all deleted and push the change to bit bucket

And then I have deleted all of my source code on both My local machine and repo.

I read that doing checkout we can restore, But couldnot understand the correct way and syntax of checkout.
I have tried :

```
`git checkout $commit~1 .`  # here I dont understand what 1 actually refers.`

 git log --diff-filter=D --summary  # from here I've viewed log summary but do not understand any thing.
```

I think if i keep palying more my deletion would be parmanent .

Please help me. 
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be how to revert a mistaken git commit. You could get better help if the question didn't mention Android studio and bitbucket.

Since you pushed the mistaken commit to another copy of the repo, the way to revert it is to add a new commit that does the reverse of the mistaken commit, e.g.

> git commit HEAD~

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert and http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

You really need to learn how git works. There are many fine books and tutorials on the subject.

Also, don't commit a change without looking it over to see if it's right.